# python importing txt file as an empty dataset

Tags: python, parsing, import

I have a dataset which has 5M rows and 15 columns. This is a text dataset.
When I import this to python, it displays this output :

```
  ÿþa           Unnamed: 1       .....   Unnamed: 14
----------    ----------                ----------    
NaN              NaN                      NaN
```

My code is below :

```
# specify your input folder's path and then read it as python dataframe

path_in = 'C:/Users/cagdas/Python_SQLite/inputs/'

df = pd.read_csv(path_in+'df.txt',delimiter="\t",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Why is this tagged with sqlite, import, and encoding? Are you having problems with any of those things? They're not mentioning in your question anywhere.

Comment: Also, is the column really named `ÿþa`? If not, what makes you think the file is encoded in ISO-8859-1?

Comment: you're right, I removed some of the unrelevant tags. i was working in sqlite , I guess I have written it by mistake. and yes, the column name literally looks like that. I know because I have selected ISO-8859-1 when I was downloading it from the source.

Comment: OK. then you need to give us a sample of the input. Not all 5 million rows, and ideally not all 15 columns, just enough for other people to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And if there's any chance that there could be an encoding problem (I mean, the source _did_ give you what seems like a mojibake column name, so can we really trust that it encoded the columns right?), it would also help to give the same input in hex format, as well as the text format.

Comment: Actually, that's not just mojibake; `ÿþ` is what you get when you read a UTF-16-LE BOM as Latin-1. So now I'm 80% sure your problem is encoding, and we definitely need the hex to debug it.